# Soap Web Service: how to protect it and make consumable only by my application ?

Tags: .net, web-services, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a simple game in Unity.

I'm also developing an asp.net soap web service to download / upload data.

I'll be host on a web server with https.

I want that only my client game can access to my web service, so i think to protect with a unique user and password (whoever run my game has the same user e password stored in source code).

Is it a correct approach ?

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: "make consumable only by my application". You can't. You can make it harder with SSL but a very determined person can circumvent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you but what i would do is:

1.- Login / Password system, the client will access and once granted a unique ID will be generated, this ID will have an expiration time, and once expired a new login is required to allow further communications

2.- Each time the client tries to access the web service it needs to send the ID, it will be confirmed in the backend and changed / refreshed as needed

As you can see is a traditional approach, a skillful programmer will break any protection you make, you can harden it with a [challenge-response authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication), in this approach both client and server must have the same algorithm. After the password authentication (or before, or never if you want) the server sends a random number that is processed by the client algorithm who will send the result as answer to the server, if the server result is the same then the client is treated as trusty and communication is allowed

You must keep your algorithm secret, if someone reverse engineer it it will become useless, and obviously you must have SSL communication to avoid man in the middle attacks and learning of your algoritm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19CE1yeKzjU